# Display letters of the string in a cell PHP

Tags: php, string, tcpdf

I'm trying to display the letters of the string, THIS CODES DISPLAY ONLY ONE STRING. I can't display when I have array of strings, also when all of the string is displayed, random letter will fill the cell. any help?

For example..

A D H I H K
S A M P L E
S T J K Q L
A A L A S T
A P P L E T

I need to output Something like this. So the words in that sample are, SAMPLE, DATA, LAST and APPLE. Hope someone can help me been doing this for almost a week.. thx

```
 $words = "SAMPLE";

    for ($r=1;$r<=$row;$r++) 
    {
        for ($c=1;$c<=$col;$c++) 
        {
            $maxWordLength=$col-$c+1;
           if($maxWordLength > 1)
           {

                $word_letter=substr($words,0,1);
                $words=substr($words,1);


            }
             else
             {

                $word_letter=$characters[mt_rand(0,$max)];
             }  



            $pdf->Cell($w,$h,$word_letter,1,0,'C');


        }
        $pdf->Ln($h);

    }
```

Comment: I thought it was "applet"!

Comment: can you give us an example value for `$row`, `$col` and `$max` (should this be `$maxWordLength`?) - also `$w` and `$h`? These are all variables that we'll need to help you debug this. Or even better, replicate your problem on http://eval.in

Comment: $row =10, $col = 10, $w=8, $h=8 , thats all the value, 
all I need is to get all the words in the array, I can only do it if 1 word, but when multiple words, its seems not working..hmm